# Найти в массиве числа и обернуть их в тег

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Приходит массив из объектов `['Персональные скидки', 'Обслуживания от 0 до 10 000 ₽']`.
Необходимо обернуть цифры в тег `<span>`. Кто подскажет как сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы обернуть можно использовать такой код:

```js
let str = '213,564,232,654.12355';

console.log(str.replace(/([0-9]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'));
```

В вашем контексте надо использовать `map`:

```js
let arr = ['Персональные скидки', 'Обслуживания от 0 до 10 000 ₽'];
arr.map((element) => element.replace(/([0-9]+)/g, '<span>$1</span>'));
```

**Обновление**

Есть такой вариант еще, но он берет последний пробел: `([0-9]+ )+`.

Для теста: https://regex101.com/r/s6prZO/1

[image: regex скрин]

Если надо и валюту учитывать, то вот так можно: `(([0-9]+ )+)[₽]{0,1}`

Comment: проверял как 10 000 обернуло?)

Comment: @WVFFLIFE 10 000 это не число. Это два числа 10 и 000. Банально: ты сможешь в качестве числа записать 10 000 в БД?

Comment: @mepihindeveloper а если необходимо обернуть 10 000 в тег, так же может быть 12 000, 16 000.
Может убирать пробел между цифрами и оборачивать, а потом обратное действие совершать?

Comment: @Gleb не очень понимаю, как сделать обратное действие. Вообще, я надо бы регулярку подобрать, но пока у меня не выходит

Comment: @Gleb обновил ответ. Вроде как твоя задача решается.

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин только странно, что в конце не добавляет "Р"

Comment: @Gleb в последней регулярке добавляется же

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин да, но если в консольке проверить, он её удаляет

Comment: @МаксимНЕпихин В контексте с map видать не работает

Comment: @Gleb замени на `<span>$&</span>`

Comment: оо, спасибо большое